# What is acceptable error rate in load testing?

Tags: jmeter

I have done a load test for a web site with JMeter. I have simulated 500 online active users and had 0,7 % error in Aggregate report. I'm getting only errors because of latency exceeding.

Is it acceptable for such amount of users? And what is an acceptable error rate in Aggregate report?

Answer (score 4):

acceptable error rate Depends/varies on the SLA's provided by your customer,developer, stakeholders (people who manages their website in your case)

as a general practice 0.5-1.0% is acceptable in general applications/websites but if its mission critical/some very important application then error rate is of high priority (maybe 0%, that will be provided as first point in  things to achieve list by your stakeholders)

Answer (score 0):

One of possible reasons of these errors could be the insufficient memory at your localhost. May be your JMeter script isn't optimized or contains listeners or a lot of assertions. If so, remove listeners and minimize assertions as you can. Follow [this performance and tuning tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips) to decrease memory usage.

Comment: I have only one assertion, it is latency limitation - 5 sec. So errors occurs only when latency exceed 5 sec. Error percentage in aggregate report after 2-3 hours of testing is 0,7% for 500 users. In SLA i have: 1. System is designed for 500 simultaneously active online users and 2. Search lasts no more 1,5-2 seconds. So system works stable, but error percentage is always 0,5-0,7%. Is it acceptable for such amount of users? Or error percentage shuld be 0%?

Comment: Nachiket answered the question related with acceptable percentage error